# Performing Modulus Arithmetic Within a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

As something new, I'm trying to complete Project Euler Problem 5, with a batch script (https://projecteuler.net/problem=5). However; I've run into a few problems. If anyone could go over my code, that'd be great.

```
@ECHO off

SET init=1
SET iter=1
SET /a func=%init% %% %iter%
cls

:Num
IF func==0 (
    IF iter==20 (
        ECHO Val = %init%
        pause
        exit
    ) ELSE (
        SET /a iter+=1
        GOTO Num
    )
) ELSE (
    SET iter=1
    SET /a init+=1
    GOTO Num
)
```

What it's meant to do is check whether the `init mod iter` returns a 0, and if it does, add 1 to the `iter` value, until it reaches 21.  However; if it does not equal 0, the iteration count will be set back to 0 and will start calculating again.

---

An example of what's MEANT to happen:

```
1 mod 1 = 0, Therefor add 1 to iter
1 mod 2 != 0, Therefor init is set to 0 and 1 is added to init
2 mod 1 = 0, Therefor add 1 to iter
2 mod 2 = 0, Therefor add 1 to iter
2 mod 3 != 0, Therefor init is set to 0 and 1 is added to init
```

And so on and so forth.

---

An example of what DOES happen:

```
1 mod 1 != 0, Therefor add 1 to init
2 mod 1 != 0, Therefor add 1 to init
3 mod 1 != 0, Therefor add 1 to init
```

And so on and so forth.

---

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've made a few changes to the code, however; now it skips the modulus arithmetic completely and says that 1 mod 1 to 20 = 0. Thoughts on why it does this? 

`@ECHO off

SET init=1
SET iter=1
SET /a func="%init% %% %iter%"
cls

:Num
IF "%func%" == "0" (
 IF "%iter%" == "21" (
  echo.
  ECHO Val = %init%
  echo.
  echo Press any key to exit . . .
  pause > nul
  exit
 ) ELSE (
  echo %init% mod %iter% = 0; CONT
  SET /a iter+=1
  GOTO Num
 )
) ELSE (
echo %init% mod %iter% != 0; BREAK
 SET iter=1
 SET /a init+=1
 GOTO Num
)`

Sorry for the ugly formatting.

Comment: You never recalculate `%func%`.

Comment: How would I incorporate this?

Comment: Move `:Num` to right above `SET /a func=%init% %% %iter%`

Comment: Your brute force approach is not practical. Assuming you work out the correct syntax and logic, I believe this approach will take many days, perhaps many weeks, to complete. Even if you optimize the code to use a FOR /L loop instead of  the relatively slow GOTO, I believe it will take many hours to complete, perhaps more than one day.

Comment: I didn't exactly create this to be practical, more along the lines of a fun challenge to learn the basics of a new language while getting something out of it. If you're able to tell me how to utilise the FOR loop, that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: You need `IF %func%==0` - your posted code is comparing "func" with "0" which is always false. You also need to update `func` inside your loop (i.e. below `:Num`).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET init=1 
SET iter=1 
cls 
set loopCounter=1
set loopBatch=1

:numLoop
SET /a func="!init! %% !iter!" 
IF !iter! == 21 (goto :done)
IF !func! == 0 (call :incIter) ELSE ( call :incInit)
SET /a loopCounter+=1 
SET /a loopBatch="%loopCounter% %% 1000" 
if !loopBatch! == 0 (echo %loopCounter% iterations done)
goto :numLoop

:incInit
  rem echo %init% mod %iter% == %func%; Increasing init
  SET iter=1 
  SET /a init+=1 
  goto :eof

:incIter
  rem echo %init% mod %iter% == %func%; Increasing iter
  SET /a iter+=1 
  goto :eof

:done
  echo. 
  ECHO Val = %init%
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to post a "practical" (!?) solution just in case someone could find it "useful" (!!?)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Our search limit 
    set "limit=20"
    rem Note: batch arithmetic is limited to 2^31 values, so 26 is the highest
    rem       value that we can directly use

    rem Initialize searched number
    set "euler5=1"

    rem Initialize list of numbers for a Erastotenes cribe
    for /l %%a in (2 1 %limit%) do set "f.%%a=%%a"

    rem Search for prime numbers and simplify (divide) greater multiples
    rem Keep multiplying as we iterate over the list 
    for /l %%a in (2 1 %limit%) do (
        if !f.%%a! gtr 1 (
            set /a "euler5*=!f.%%a!"
            for %%c in (!f.%%a!) do for /l %%b in (%%a %%a %limit%) do (
                set /a "f.%%b/=%%c"
            )
        )
    )

    rem Echo solution
    echo %euler5%
```

Answer (score 0):

according to this link:[link](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) there is a modulus operator.

So you can try this instead

```
@echo off

::we should start with 21 because we know that all numbers from 1-20
::cannot be divided by 20 all 20 times.
::This will also fix the problem of an unwanted a zero remainder at the
::early numbers

set count=21
set divide=1
::We need to set enabledelayedexpansion so we can use ! as a varible 
::expander.
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:loop
:: begin the modulus operator.
set /a remainder=!count!%%!divide!
if %remainder%==0 (
if %divide%==20
::Yea!
echo number found:%count%
::Don't forget to pause
::or else you cant see the number.
pause
) else (
set /a divide=%divide%+1
::equivelent to set /a divide+=1
goto :loop
)
) else (
set /a count=%count%+1
goto :loop
)
```

Although this does not fix your script, it is definitly a faster way.